# Comments Lost Days after Posted

Tags: support, comments

Recently I noticed twice that my comments under answers ([answer 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253315/207952) and [answer 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252830/207952)) were gone several days after they were posted. In answer 2, only part of the comments, which I actually referred to in my answer, were lost. Is it a system bug or is it deleted according to forum rules?

Answer (score 11):

I deleted the comments in questions. Most of them fell under the "obsolete" removal clause. In addition some not so productive discussion was removed.

[This FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/222299) has some more information on how comments work and who can delete comments.

If I accidentally removed too much don't hesitate to comment the same again (unless a diamond moderator tells you otherwise).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. For answer 1 it was OK that the comments were deleted.  But for answer 2, the original comments were a short discussion on the algorithm complexity. It was not possible to reproduce them entirely. The reference to the comments in my answer were invalidated and it would take extra work to fix the text.

Answer (score 7):

Comments are third-rate citizens on the Stack Exchange network. They can be deleted almost at-will. Please see the [MSE FAQ on how comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/269301).

[Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

This is not unique to Code Review. It works like this everywhere on the network.